# Built button is not showing in iTunes connect and a simple app size is big

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store-connect

I created a test app. In app there is nothing much. I was using only one button in my main storyboard. After that when I export it app size is 59 MB.
I am surprised. I don't understand what has happened. My question is how can I reduce the size?

Also, I have another problem. When I upload this app to iTunes Connect, my build button is not showing. After that I try to upload again and Xcode is telling me this binary exists. Then I changed the app version and upload it but still build button is not showing.

[showing processing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSBQb.png)

[+ button is not showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvsKY.png)

Comment: These are two completely different questions. Please only post one question at a time.

Comment: Oky, next Time i wii do  But How can i solve this ?  @maddy

Answer (score 1):

Most likely is because the app you uploaded is processing.

When a new app is uploaded to `iTunesConnect` generally it take about >20min before the process is complete. After processing a `+` button will appear for you to add the uploaded build.

To check if the app you uploaded is under processing, you can click on the `Activity` tab on the top menu bar.

Comment: Already i added 1.0 and 1.1 in iTunesConnect. 1.0 was upload before 24 hour now. But + button not appear. when i uploaded and go to Activity tab i was saw the app is processing after that it's not showing @zac kwan

Comment: have the processing of the app been completed?

Comment: If is finished processed, you should be able to see the blue add button and select the build you have uploaded. Can you look at the first screenshot here and ensure that you are at the correct app version. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SubmittingTheApp.html

Comment: i uploaded 2 screenshot can you please look those ?

Comment: The screenshot one show processing for version 1.2. But screenshot 2 is on version 1.0. Both is not matched

Comment: Either you upload a app that is version 1.0 or create a new version 1.2 on iTunesConnect

Comment: How can i change the version  in iTunesConnect ?? isn,t it change automatically ??

Comment: No is not, maybe you need to understand more on how this works. My suggestion would be to go study the documentation or look for tutorial online before wasting too much time exploring yourself.

Comment: Also i have same problem another app. i used same version but has same problem

Comment: Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the build wasn't processing within the **Activity** section.

I think the problem is archiving more than once with the same *Version* and *Build* number.

Rather than changing the *Version* in iTunes Connect and in Xcode, I changed the *Build* number from 1 to 1.0. Then I archived and uploaded, the build is now in the **Activity** section processing.